# Missing netcat server crashes android app

Tags: java, android, sockets

Details: Java android app, with Java ADT. I simulate the server locally for development by listening on 6789 with netcat.

Not having the server open before running the app make the app crash at startup here:

```
try {
        this.clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 6789);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code runs in the onCreate method.

Also, each time I close the app the server (the running instance of cmd) closes as well.
This is a bit annoying especially since I don't know why.

As a work-around I looked up some way to programmatically start the server script:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cmd /c start C:/start_server.bat");
```

...but this failed because no root access.

How can I improve this ? Would creating multiple sockets for each function make sense ?

UPDATE: logcat

```
08-12 17:28:35.920: I/dalvikvm(2246): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-12 17:28:35.942: I/dalvikvm(2246): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-12 17:30:26.291: W/System.err(2246): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
08-12 17:30:26.298: W/System.err(2246):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
08-12 17:30:26.298: W/System.err(2246):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
08-12 17:30:26.298: W/System.err(2246):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:705)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:150)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:176)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at com.example.robot_industrial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-12 17:30:26.312: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 17:30:26.318: W/System.err(2246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add the logcat to the post

Comment: Your code should handle not having a server to talk to.  As for starting it, you obviously can't execute a windows .bat file on your Android device, especially if it is stored on the C: drive of your windows box.  Can you run the server in a loop in your bat file, run on your windows box?